# Use Promise function in Angular 6 Data Binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I'm having an issue where I am using an async function in Angular 6 data binding:

```
<span *ngIf="application.status == 'in-progress'; else new">
  {{getAssignedUser(application.user_id)}}
</span>
```

The `getAssignedUser()` is an async function which fetches a document from Firestore and I want to display the assigned user's firstname which I received from Firestore. The only problem here is I can't display the firstname value OnInit. If I insert a button and add a click event, it displays the name.

**Component:**

```
async getAssignedUser(id): Promise<string> {
    if (id != null) {
        return this._usersService
        .getUserById(id)
        .then(data => {
            this.assignedUser = data.user_fname;
            return this.assignedUser;
        })
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
getUserById(id): any {
    let user: any;
    user = this.afs.collection('agents').doc(id).ref.get().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            user = doc.data();
            console.log(user);
            return user;
        }
        else {
            console.log('No such document');
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error getting document: ', error);
    })
    return user;
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can you provide us with a stackblitz fro your example to be more clear ?

Comment: What is it you're trying to display? You're doing `{{getAssignedUser(application.user_id)}}`, but `getAssignedUser` returns a Promise. You could use an `async` pipe, like `{{getAssignedUser(application.user_id) | async }}`

Comment: @user184994 I'm trying to display a string actually. I don't know how to get the string value from the Promise. It's working with a click event. To be even more precise, I'm actually using an id to retrieve data from another Firestore document and want to access that document values.

Comment: You can try using the `async` pipe to get the value out,  which would be `{{getAssignedUser(application.user_id) | async }}`

Comment: I tried, it is not working. Actually my browser is freezing as if I'm stuck in an infinite loop. The function keeps on calling and never stop.

Comment: That;s one of the downsides of calling functions from within the template: the function is called for every change detection cycle. Instead, why not called `getUserById` in `ngOnInit`, and just use `{{assignedUser}}` in your template?

Comment: @user184994 I have to pass an argument, id. And the case scenario is, I have a table with multiple applications. I have a field Assigned To which displays user that is assigned to the application. In Firestore I have 2 collections, one is for Applications and other one is Users. Applications contain a user_id which will link to the Users collection to get the assigned user. I don't really know how to use it in     ngOnInit.

Answer (score 0):

> Issue

The issue with making the call `getAssignedUser` from the html and expecting to return the value. This will not guarantee because `getAssignedUser` performs async operation. You had mentioned the async operation on `getAssignedUser` however does not returns any `Observable` or `Promise`.

> Solution

You need to change in both services and component. Function should return the Promise to handle this case.

#### Service:

```
  getUserById(id): any {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      this.afs.collection('agents').doc(id).ref.get().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          user = doc.data();
          console.log(user);
          resolve(user);
        }
        else {
          resolve(null); //<-- you can reject if you want.
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

#### Component:

```
async getAssignedUser(id): Promise<string> {
        return this._usersService
        .getUserById(id);
}
```

#### html

```
<span *ngIf="application.status == 'in-progress'; else new">
  {{getAssignedUser(application.user_id)} | async}
</span>
```

*Important : You should not function in html, it may lead to multiple call and will impact on the performance. Better would be to use function instead.*

> Note : code is written directly to stackoverflow editor so there could be typo or syntactical error. So please correct yourself.

Comment: async is required only to observable, not for promises.

Comment: @sleepz - please create stackblitz demo to get it fix quicker and easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Sunil Singh Above Answer, small correction in template file. async operator is mainly used for observable. You can call without that it should work.

```
<span *ngIf="application.status == 'in-progress'; else new">
  {{getAssignedUser(application.user_id)}}
</span>
```

Comment: Not true, the async pipe also works with promises. Please check the [description in the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#description)